# Input lag with R-Go Split Break Ergonomic Keyboard

Tags: distribution-choice

I'm experiencing input lag on Ubuntu 20.04 with the R-Go Split Break Ergonomic Keyboard.

An amazon reviewer [1] points to the fact that this problem does not occur on all linux distributions. Is anyone using a linux distribution where this problem does not occur?

R-Go support suggested using wayland. This did not help.

[1] urburburb comment at [https://www.amazon.com/R-Go-Tools-Keyboard-RGOSP-USWIBL-Integrated/dp/B071GCDWN7](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B071GCDWN7)

Comment: The input lag with the R-Go Split Break Ergonomic Keyboard on Linux Mint 20.1 Cinnamon is not as bad as in Ubuntu. But still occurs. Then input lag in the application xed text editor is less than in firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same issue on Ubuntu 22.04. I have two computer, one laptop where the keyboard is working just fine, and one desktop computer where the keyboard is having big delays when I type two keys from each keyboard (left and right keyboard). I have used https://github.com/Ckath/mergeinputs, but it did not fixed my problem. Maybe you can give it a try, it fixed this issues for some guys.

Any news from your side ?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/422739)